# Java Thread CPU usage

Tags: java, multithreading, quicksort

I am currently trying to write a quick sort algorithm in Java with usage of threads. But a CPU utilization is never 100%, no matter the length of an array. Can you please help me to find out the problem? Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr;
        Random random = new Random();
        arr = new int[53000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            arr[i] = random.nextInt();
        }
        SortThread sortThread = new SortThread(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
        Thread threadSort = new Thread(sortThread);
        threadSort.start();
    }

}
public class SortThread implements Runnable {

    private int[] arr;
    private int start;
    private int end;

    public SortThread(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
        this.arr = arr;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (start < end){
            int partitionIndex = partition(arr, start, end);
            SortThread sortThreadLeft = new SortThread(arr, start, partitionIndex - 1);
            SortThread sortThreadRight = new SortThread(arr, partitionIndex + 1, end);
            Thread sortLeft = new Thread(sortThreadLeft);
            Thread sortRight = new Thread(sortThreadRight);
            sortLeft.start();
            sortRight.start();
        }
    }

    private int partition(int arr[], int begin, int end){

        int pivot = arr[end];
        int i = (begin - 1);

        for (int j = begin; j < end; j++){
            if (arr[j] <= pivot ){
                i++;
                int swpTemp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = swpTemp;
            }
        }

        int swapTemp = arr[i + 1];
        arr[i + 1] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = swapTemp;
        return i + 1;
    }
}
```

In the `Main` class I define the array with random elements. In the `SortThread` class I sort the array using quick sort algorithm. Each sub array is sorted separately in different threads. In a theory this should occupy all the processing power of each CPU. But in practice only 40% is used, no matter the length of an array.

Comment: You are creating way too many threads. At some point there will be thousands of threads that do nothing but sort two elements, which is extremly inefficient. You are spending more time creating/scheduling/terminating threads than actually sorting the array. You should switch to using a thread pool and rethink how to split your task in parts that are large enough to be executed by a seperate thread each.

Comment: Try using a fallback to the none-threaded sort when partition size is less than ... say 1024, experiment with (de-)increasing the value to find a fitting number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I solved:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

public class Main {

    static long start;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numOfThreads = 8;
        try {
            numOfThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            System.out.println("Number of threads: " + numOfThreads);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid number of threads: Default 8");
        }

        SortThread.executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numOfThreads);

        int[] arr = new int[Integer.parseInt(args[1])];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            arr[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 256) + 1;
        }

        SortThread sortThread = new SortThread(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
        Thread threadSort = new Thread(sortThread);
        start = System.nanoTime();
        threadSort.start();
    }

}

class SortThread implements Runnable {
    static ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    private int[] arr;
    private int start;
    private int end;

    public SortThread(int[] arr, int start, int end) {

        this.arr = arr;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (start < end){
            int partitionIndex = partition(arr, start, end);

            SortThread sortThreadLeft = new SortThread(arr, start, partitionIndex - 1);
            SortThread sortThreadRight = new SortThread(arr, partitionIndex + 1, end);

            Thread sortLeft = new Thread(sortThreadLeft);
            Thread sortRight = new Thread(sortThreadRight);

            SortThread.executor.execute(sortLeft);
            SortThread.executor.execute(sortRight);
        } else {
            if (SortThread.executor.getQueue().size() == 0 && SortThread.executor.getActiveCount() == 1) {
                System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - Main.start)/1000000);
                SortThread.executor.shutdown();
            }
        }
    }

    private static int partition(int[] arr, int begin, int end){

        int pivot = arr[end];
        int i = (begin - 1);

        for (int j = begin; j < end; j++){
            if (arr[j] <= pivot ){

                i++;
                int swpTemp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = swpTemp;

            }
        }

        int swapTemp = arr[i + 1];
        arr[i + 1] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = swapTemp;

        return i + 1;
    }
}
```

Just created executor and added all of them to the pool.

Comment: This is not enough. The contents of `arr` need to be safely published after computation is completed. [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) should suit your use case.